# How to get img url from html text

Tags: java, android, html

In Android development, how can I get an image URL or load an image from the HTML text shown below? I get it from HTML, and I want to get an image URL from this code:

```html
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 16px;"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-2699 size-large" src="http://www.helalsaglikliyasam.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/helal-parti-1-1024x258.jpg" alt="helal parti-1" width="750" height="189" srcset="http://www.helalsaglikliyasam.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/helal-parti-1-300x76.jpg 300w, http://www.helalsaglikliyasam.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/helal-parti-1-768x193.jpg 768w, http://www.helalsaglikliyasam.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/helal-parti-1-1024x258.jpg 1024w, http://www.helalsaglikliyasam.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/helal-parti-1-560x141.jpg 560w, http://www.helalsaglikliyasam.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/helal-parti-1.jpg 1564w" sizes="(max-width: 750px) 100vw, 750px" /></span></p>
```

I want to get src="http://www.helalsaglikliyasam.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/helal-parti-1-1024x258.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use an HTML parser -- there are several Java HTML parsing libraries that can be found with a quick search.

A quick and dirty, way, however, would be to search the input string for the `src="` declaration, like so:

```
int index = input.indexOf("src=\"");
String substr = input.substring(index + 5);
int endIndex = substr.indexOf("\"");
String imgUrl = substr.substring(0, endIndex);
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, so it may have errors.  It also makes a lot of assumptions which may not be true -- which is why you should use a library for this sort of thing!

Edit: Fixed one error after testing (had to use a different machine than the one I'm typing this on).  It should work for you now -- but again, you should really use a library.

Answer (score 0):

to create an image in HTML just type:

```html
<img src="www.example.com/images/this-one.png" alt="an image" />
```

you may nest the img tag into a p and or span tag as needed.
Just a note, code is much easier to read when you use external style sheets

Comment: Sorry I mean in Android development. I get it from html code and I want to get image url from this code